# Find COM object (Corel.Application) for multiple instances having process ID or MainWindowHandle

Tags: com, pid, comobject

I have an Client Server application doing the next:
The server starts and listen to a specific port.
Many corelDraw sesions manually or programmatically start. Each corel session (client) connect to server sending the current process ID. The server keeps all connections in a listView and based on each connection EndPoint can change (send and receive) messages.
Now I would like to use COM object of a specific such process ID.
I tried:

```
using corel = Corel.Interop.VGCore;

int processID = Convert.ToInt32(lstClients.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text);//process ID string
Process corProc = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
int hwnd = (int)Process.GetProcessById(corProc).MainWindowHandle
this.Activate();
bool IsCom = corProc.GetType().IsCOMObject; // return false...
corApp = (corel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Corel.Application") // returns just the last session (not according to existing process ID
//tried also:
corApp = (corel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(corProc.Handle); // error...
//tried:
corApp = (corel.Application)Convert.ChangeType(corProc, typeof(corel.Application)); // error: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'
```

Is there a way to obtain corel COM object to give me the oportunity to use Corel.Application object like that?

```
MessageBox.Show(corApp.Documents.Count.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no general purpose mechanism to get an object from a PID, but depending upon the implementation of the OLE server, you may be able to use [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx).  See [Launching Office Apps Programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/11/30/launching-office-apps-programmatically/) for a similar example targeting PowerPoint.

You may also [try using RotView](http://alax.info/blog/1444) to see if the application is registered in the Running Object Table.  Visual Studio, for example, registers with a moniker of `!VisualStudio.DTE.14.0:21604` where 14.0 is the version and 21604 is the process id.

[image: ROTView showing a VisualStudio entry with the process id]

Comment: Thnks!  I already tried your first suggestion but it works well for Microsoft COM objects where you know the guide: IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}". I couldn't find a way to determine it for corel application.   For the second suggestion I couldn't find that RotView... Maybe it will help me in order to find the guide...